# "Type is not defined" when I want to add my custom class as settings type

Tags: c#, .net, system.configuration, applicationsettingsbase

I want to add this class as setting's type:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MY_PROJECT.SUB_PROJECT
{
    [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
    public class Configs: List<ConfigData>
    {
        Configs(int capacity): base(capacity) { }

        public string GroupName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So what I did:

1. Select *Browse...* in the type dropbox:
    [image]
2. I cannot see the `MY_PROJECT` namespace anywhere:
   [image]
3. So I typed the full type manually:
   [image]
4. The result is an error:

   ```
   Type 'MY_PROJECT.SUB_PROJECT.Configs' is not defined.
   ```

   [image]

I also tried `SUB_PROJECT.Configs` and `Configs` alone. Nothing helped. Why does my class not show in the browser?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add the compiled class to the project references. I guess one way would be to move it to it's own .dll

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean here. I've read some tutorials on this and they mentioned no such thing.

Comment: Perform a project build before you try to use the type in the settings dialog.  You do not need an external library for the type as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull something in as a reference you need to have it compiled as a dll file.  In Visual Studio they refer to this as a "Library" which is really just a class without a main function.  Other option is to just leave it in the same namespace and pull the class into whatever else your working on.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and it was due to an *Inconsistent accessibility* error. Make sure that any 'required' type/field is globally accessible (*public*?). For the OP's case, making the **constructor** public solves the issue:

```
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
public class Configs: List<ConfigData>
{ 
    public Configs(int capacity): base(capacity) { }
  //  ^^
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

In my case this was the problem:

```
internal struct NativeType
{
    //...
}

[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
public class NativeTypeWrapper
{
    public NativeType type; // This will not work because NativeType 
                            // is less accessible than NativeTypeWrapper...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I was doing exactly the same: creating a custom class to use in Application Settings. In my case, I followed the steps outlined in this very informative article:
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CustomAppSettings.aspx

I should note the article is written for C#, and I painstakingly converted it to VB until it worked. I had to solve the `Type...is not defined` error the hard way: relentlessly experimenting until I got it to work.

I will describe my first solution, one which was not mentioned in the article, probably because it's for C# instead of VB, and that is: put the custom class or classes each in their own `.vb` files. For instance: `Employee.vb` and `Room.vb`. This is the only way I could make it work perfectly with no errors. After doing this and rebuilding the solution, I was then able to add my custom class as an Application Setting, but of course only by manually typing the full name `TestProject.Employee` in the `Select a Type` dialog.

However, following the article I linked above, if I put all the class definitions in the `Module1.vb` file with `Sub Main()`, the `Select a Type` dialog cannot find them, and I receive the `Type...is not defined` error.

And the cause of this error seems to be shortcomings in the code & design of the Applications Settings system and Settings page of the Project Properties dialog. I say this because of the solution I found: I hacked my classes into the settings the hard way.

What I mean by that is I initially created the setting with the name `DefaultEmployee` and type of `String`. Then I used the `Find In Files` dialog to find all instances of `DefaultEmployee` and replaced the appropriate instances of `String` with `TestProject.Employee`.

The files I made replacements in are: `App.config`, `Settings.Designer.vb`, and `Settings.settings`.

And it worked..! Sort of. I should say the code ran fine and it did what was expected. But...the Application Settings dialog didn't like it. After I made the changes, there are various errors from the Project Properties/Settings system every time I opened it. But as I said, it still works.

Thus...my only conclusion is the coding of the Settings system is not designed to handle this situation, and if you wish to have the most reliable & error-free experience, it's best to put each of the custom classes in their own `.vb` class file.

On the other hand, if you wish to become very adventurous, you could create your own Applications Settings system, as the author of this article did. I have not read all of this yet, but scanning through it seems very interesting:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/dec/28/building-a-better-net-application-configuration-class-revisited